# Azure App Services Web App not registering update

Tags: azure, caching, azure-web-app-service

I have a Azure App Service app that I'm trying to get deployed.

Today I ran into an issue where .NET informed me (via the yellow screen of death when I browse to the URL of my app) that I had a missing DLL (for the purposes of this question I don't think it really matters).
I used `FileZilla` to publish my changes in an attempt to do a manual deployment first and then work my way to automate it.

After so many attempts to fix it I later realized that the error message never changed. I did something more severe and renamed my `bin` folder into something completely different and the exact same error message would appear.
I've stopped the service, restarted it, and as mentioned, renamed folders, etc. and still the exact same error message persisted.

I also decided to open up the Azure Portal Console for my App Service app to browse a bit and to my amazement, nothing seemed to have reflected at all. The FTP shows one thing and the Console shows another.

Would anyone have any idea as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got it to work and I will share what I tried.
I deleted the web app and created it again (I found this to be important the first time around). This was quite time consuming and did help but it wasn't long before the same problem happened again.

Then I finally found a solution that seems to give me consistent results:
I kept on editing the `Web.config` which seems to force a recompile and clear some sort of cache. So each time the web app stopped updating, I would make a slight change in the `Web.config`, upload it via FTP and the app finally updates.

If anyone has any more details on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear if ever reached a point of continuos deployment. it looks like you stayed with FTP. with that assumption, lets continue. 

When doing a deployment, although time consuming, I always empty the server and do a fresh deployment. I have also noticed similar caching issue. I dont know why but I think files do get cached. 

Further, I use FTP as a last resort or for minor one time deployments. I would advice you stick to CICD for an ongoing project.

Comment: Hi @Jay, I totally agree, we want to move over to the Pipeline deployment and have attempted that but due to the problems that we encountered we found it very counter-intuitive to work that way around. So we first want to get a manual deployment working before we sort out the automated deployments. I definitely don't like deploying it manually again and again.

Comment: if so, I would strongly recommend you simply do FTP via Filezilla or similar client. the visual studio publish option is not good at all. In my experience, it does not work as expected.

Hope you fix the pending issues and move to CICD fast :)